# Wordpress API - post meta field

Tags: php, python, wordpress, meta

I am trying to create a post via WP API and I am using python to send http requests. So an example http request body would look like this:

```
body = json.dumps(dict(
    slug='test',
    status='publish',
    title='test',
    excerpt='test',
    content='test',
    author=1,
    comment_status='open',
    ping_status='open',
    categories=[1],
    meta={
        '_links_to': 'https://google.com',
        '_knawatfibu_url': 'https://some-image.jpg'
    }
))
```

And the sending itself looks like this:

```
headers = {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'Authorization': 'Basic ' + base64.b64encode(f'{settings.WP_LOGIN}:{settings.WP_PASS}'.encode()).decode()
}

response = requests.post(settings.WP_HOST + '/wp-json/wp/v2/posts', json=data, headers=headers)
```

Now the good news is that it creates the post.

But it does not set meta fields which makes some of the plugins to have no effect. How do I *enforce* setting of meta fields via API?

I have heared that I need to expose certain meta fields via PHP code. But how do I do that and most importantly - where do I do that?

**EDIT:**

I have tried to add this PHP piece of code to *functions.php* and ideed it showed all meta fields on API GET call, but setting those field was still not possible.

```
add_action( 'rest_api_init', 'create_api_posts_meta_field' );
function create_api_posts_meta_field() {
    // register_rest_field ( 'name-of-post-type', 'name-of-field-to-return', array-of-callbacks-and-schema() )
    register_rest_field( 'post', 'meta', array(
        'get_callback' => 'get_post_meta_for_api',
        'schema' => null,
        )
    );
}
function get_post_meta_for_api( $object ) {
    //get the id of the post object array
    $post_id = $object['id'];

    //return the post meta
    return get_post_meta( $post_id );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Found an answer.

Simply put this PHP code snippet in your *functions.php*:

```
add_action("rest_insert_post", function ($post, $request, $creating) {
    $metas = $request->get_param("meta");

    if (is_array($metas)) {

        foreach ($metas as $name => $value) {
            update_post_meta($post->ID, $name, $value);
        }

    }
}, 10, 3);
```