# Python WordPress REST API - Post Featured Image as external URL

Tags: python, wordpress, wordpress-rest-api

is it possibile to post in wordpress the featured image as hotlink (external url), without hosting the image on the server?

See the line that should be fixed:

```
"featured_image": 'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/it/f/fc/Pippo_Disney.png'
```

in

```
postDict = {
    "title": 'Hi',
    "content": 'My Content',
    "date": '2020-08-17T10:16:34',
    "featured_image": 'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/it/f/fc/Pippo_Disney.png', # IMPORTANT
}
```

If it is not possibile, any ideas to do that is really welcome, thank you

Comment: Thank you all, I found finally the solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56743795/wordpress-api-post-meta-field

Answer (score 0):

By default, WordPress doesn't support external links for featured images. However, there're some plugins implementing this feature:

- [Featured Image from URL (FIFU)](https://wordpress.org/plugins/featured-image-from-url/)
- [Featured Image by URL](https://wordpress.org/plugins/featured-image-by-url/)

You'll have to research their source code to understand how to use them from the REST API.

Comment: thanks, I knew both plugins. The first allows to use the rest API only in the premium version (I'm not considering this plugin for this purpose), while the second it is interesting but I could not find a way to use it to solve the issue. I opened a ticket that describe my tests, if you'd like to have a look: https://github.com/Knawat/featured-image-by-url/issues/49

Answer (score 0):

There is a simple trick for this. You can paste a link for external img for example to excerpt, and then you can get this url by using get_the_excerpt
https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_excerpt/.
In posts listing use

```
<img src="<?php echo get_the_excerpt( $post_id ); ?>">
```

Comment: thanks, but I'm using the excerpt field to upload the excerpt  text. How to solve this?

Comment: You can use ACF plugin to add custom field to posts.
https://wordpress.org/plugins/advanced-custom-fields/

Answer (score 0):

Just insert image as HTML and it will auto-make it the featured image
`"<img src={img} width="900" height="400" />"`

https://wordpress.org/plugins/auto-post-thumbnail/
(Use old version of plugin, New version is broken)

Answer (score 0):

I use this simple code and it worked for me. This code will give you the image ID. 'featured_media': find_id(imageURL). I hope this code will work for you

```
import requests
import json


url= 'https://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2023/04/image.jpg'

r = requests.get('https://example.com/wp-json/wp/v2/media')
event = r.json()

def find_id(m_url):
    for i in event:
        if i['guid']['rendered'] == m_url:
            return (i['id'])
        
print(find_id(url))
```